# How to calculate accuracy from table matrix

Tags: r, k-means

I'm using `table` to show results from the `kmeans` cluster vs. the actual class values.

[image]

How can I calculate the % accuracy based on that table. I know how to do it manually.

Iris-setosa had all 50 in cluster 2 while Iris-versicolor had two in the other cluster.

Is there a way to calculate the % like `Incorrectly classified instances: 52%`

I would like to print the confusion matrix by classes and clusters. Something lke this:

```
   0   1  <-- assigned to cluster
 380 120 | 1
 135 133 | 0

Cluster 0 <-- 1
Cluster 1 <-- 0

Incorrectly clustered instances :   255.0    33.2031 %
```

Comment: Can you post some example data and how your desired result looks like? `prop.table`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `diag()` to select the cases on the diagonal and use that to calculate (in)accuracy as shown below:

```
sum(diag(d))/sum(d) #overall accuracy
1-sum(diag(d))/sum(d) #incorrect classification
```

You can also use this to calculate the number of cases (in)correctly classified:

```
sum(diag(d)) #N cases correctly classified
sum(d)-sum(diag(d)) #N cases incorrectly classified
```

*where* `d` is your confusion matrix

Comment: This solution does not work if there is a _label switching issue_. Ex : `set.seed(1); x <- sample(c(1, 2, 3), 20, replace=TRUE); y <- 4 - x;    sum(diag( table(y,x))) # = 7` which is completely wrong.

Comment: In your example, 7 is the expected value. `diag` captures the diagonal that where x and y _agree_ (i.e., 1,1; 2,2; & 3,3), which is needed to capture accuracy. This corresponds to [1] 0, [2] 7, & [3] 0, which sum to 7.

Comment: and this is wrong, because in this example accuracy should sum on `[1, 3]+[2, 2] + [3, 1]`, that is why `diag`is not enough.

Comment: Hm that's not a typical interpretation of a confusion matrix as asked by the OP. See http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix